# WiFi doesn't work after suspend 18.04 HP Laptop

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, suspend

I am able to connect to wifi before suspend, but afterwards it fails to connect. The network is listed but when I click connect it keeps on giving me the error `Connection Failed. Activation of network connection failed`.

Wireless info (after it stopped working): [Link](https://pastebin.com/tkkRF4aF)

Manufacturer: HP Laptop 15-bs0xx (8329)

**Edit**

`dkms status`

```
btrtl-rtl8723de, 0.1~bionic, 4.15.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
btrtl-rtl8723de, 0.1~bionic, 5.0.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168, 8.045.08, 4.15.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168, 8.045.08, 5.0.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414, 5.0.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10, 4.4.0-137-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10, 4.4.0-138-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10, 4.4.0-141-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10, 4.4.0-145-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10, 4.4.0-148-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.10, 4.4.0-157-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `dkms status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
rm -r rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.10 --all
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo cp -r rtlwifi_new/firmware/rtlwifi/ /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
echo "options rtl8723de ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl-wifi.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: it works but now bluetooth fails to connect if the WiFi is on. I will create a separate question for that though.

Comment: That git repo doesn't exist now. Any idea which repo to use?